# sed command is not working properly

Tags: sed

I'm trying to replace the word in shell script with `sed -e command` but its not replacing , please help on that, i have tried the below

we have separate file in `/data/docs/config.log`, in that file there is a word ?account for example ,

username acc, passsword acc, ?account.name

this ?account word needs to be replaced with word 'GLOBAL' using sed -e command ,

```
reacc = GLOBAL

sed -e "s/?account/$reacc/g" /data/docs/config.log > /data/docs/newconfig.log
```

but here the file newconfig.log has created with 0 size , no output written to the file , its not replacing its an empty file,

the output should be `username acc, passsword acc, GLOBAL.name in newconfig.log`

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `reacc = GLOBAL` is not a valid shell variable assignment, you need to remove the spaces. `?` is a regex special character which might need escaping (but might not when at the start of the pattern). Are you sure `config.log` has contents? Did you accidentally run `sed -e .... /data/docs/config.log > /data/docs/config.log` and zero the config.log file by accident?

Comment: Could not reproduce on Bash. What shell are you using?

Comment: the script is ,    #! /bin/sh

Comment: Thanks Etan , i remved the space but stil empty file only generated , yes config.log has the below content username acc, passsword acc, ?account.name, if i check with echo $reacc its giving correct output as GLOBALS , also i tried with static output like sed -e "s/?account/$reacc/g" /data/docs/config.log >$1 but no result

Answer (score 1):

Being the only person who can reproduce the problem, you are pretty much on your own. There are plenty of things you can do to analyze the problem, though.

- Double-check the shell. Don't have blind faith in `#!/bin/sh`. In cygwin for example, `/bin/sh` is an alias for bash. Verify with: `echo $SHELL`
- Check permissions and file system. Do you have rights to write to the output file? Is the disk full? Does `cat /data/docs/config.log > /data/docs/newconfig.log` work? Test again in a different folder.
- Double-check the output file. Is it really empty, or is the file system just slow with updating the file size? Is `sed` really finished? Test without output redirection; see if the output is dumped to stdout.
- Test with a small file; one or two lines is enough.
- If even that does not work, then test `sed` itself. Who knows, maybe you have a weird alias that hides the real `sed`. The most trivial filter is `sed -e ''`, which should simply echo every line you type (just like `cat` without parameters). Does that work? Then try some simple patterns.

Systematically iterate between test cases that succeed and test case that fail, until you have found the breaking point. Doing so, you should be able to find the cause. Sorry, that's all I can do for you right now.

Answer (score 0):

Remove spaces around `=`. Try after making

```
reacc=GLOBAL
```

Comment: thanks removed space and tried with reacc=GLOBAL but no luck still o size file